# Prove that a holomorphic function injective in an annulus is injective in the whole ball

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $f: B(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic and suppose $\exists\ r \in (0,1)$ such that $f$ is injective in $A = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : r < |z| < 1\}$. Prove that $f$ is injective.

I tried using Rouché theorem, or the identity theorem, but I don't know what to do. Any hints? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is quite non-trivial. Suppose $z_1,z_2\in B(0,1)$ are such that $f(z_1)=f(z_2)=z_0$. Take a circle $\gamma\in A$ such that $z_1,z_2\in Int(\gamma)$. Then observe that $f(\gamma)$ is a Jordan curve (this is where you use the injectivity of $f$ in $A$) and thus by Jordan Curve Theorem, $\text{Ind}(f(\gamma),z_0)\leq1$, ignoring orientation. However by the argument principle, $$\text{Ind}(f(\gamma),z_0)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma\dfrac{f'}{f-z_0}\geq2$$

This gives the required contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm not sure I can use that, as it's an exam question and that theorem isn't usually taught...

Comment: @SeñorBilly, I'll try myself, as well as ask people regarding an "easier" proof. Meanwhile I suggest you understand the JCT, for it is very intuitive, extremely handy and incredibly hard to prove ( at least for me).

Comment: I'm a little familiarized by it! However, I have never seen a proof of it; I'm really curious...after my exam tomorrow I'll look for one :)

Comment: Why is $\operatorname{Ind}(f(\gamma),z_0)=1$?

Comment: As $f(\gamma)$ is a Jordan Curve, it divides the plane into two connected components, the inside and the outside. The inside has winding number $1$, whilst the outside has zero.

Comment: @Hmm. So why is $z_0$ inside $f(\gamma)$?

Comment: @WimC, good point. In any case the proof is repairable. I've edited.

Comment: Could one not use the open mapping theorem here? We can show that locally this function looks like f(z) = kz for the annulus, but this local condition continues inside the annulus...

Comment: Why would $f$ locally be of that form?

Comment: In the exam, it is perhaps sufficient to use that the winding number of a holomorphic function is always increasing with rising radius. And since the winding number for radius $\approx 1$ is 0 or 1 for any center value, you get the overall injectivity.